# Как посчитать количество элементов JSON с определенным значением?

Tags: python

JSON:

```
{'main':[{'category':0, 'name':'One'},
{'category':1, 'name':'Two'},
{'category':0, 'name':'Three'}]}
```

Нужно через цикл вывести на print все элементы, у которых category:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {'main':[{'category':0, 'name':'One'},
{'category':1, 'name':'Two'},
{'category':0, 'name':'Three'}]}

for i in a['main']:
    if i['category'] == 1:
        print(i)
```